# Issue with Hudson/Jenkins pulling from a CVS repo

Tags: hudson, cvs, jenkins, cvsnt

I am trying to use Hudson to do CI on a CVS repository but I receive the following error when I try to run the build:

> Started by user admin
>   [Pilot1] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\CVS Suite\CVSNT\cvs.exe" -Q -z3 -d :sserver:*login*:_*server*:/CVSRepo co -P -d **workspace** -D "Thursday, March 3, 2011 2:20:08 PM UTC" **ITitC**/
>
> cvs checkout: in directory .:
>
> cvs checkout: cannot open CVS/Entries for reading: No such file or directory
>   java.io.IOException: No such directory exists. Did you specify the correct branch? Perhaps you specified a tag: c:\ *path*\workspace
>
> at hudson.scm.CVSSCM.archive(CVSSCM.java:474)
>       at hudson.scm.CVSSCM.access$100(CVSSCM.java:123)
>       at hudson.scm.CVSSCM$1.invoke(CVSSCM.java:381)
>       at hudson.scm.CVSSCM$1.invoke(CVSSCM.java:374)
>       at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:753)

I am able to successfully do an update if I remove the "ITitC" (the module) at the end of the command and run it directly through the cmd prompt.  I was also able to quickly create a folder with that name inside of the "workspace" directory at the start of the Hudson build but it is deleted with each new build.

Is there a way I can force Hudson or CVSNT to create folders as needed either before each build or by default?  Is this a problem with CVSNT?  I'm not too attached to CVSNT and am willing to replace it with a better option.

Comment: Two things: 1. Your CVSROOT string looks strange but that might just be an artefact of obfusciation... A connection string for `:sserver:` should look like this: `:sspi:user@server:/CVSRepo` (note the @ instead of a colon). 2. The "ITitC" in your commandline is not a branch, it's the name of the module you're trying to checkout. If it is indeed the name of a branch then you should use `-r ITitC` instead. You'd still need to specify the module you want to check out, though. If you want to checkout the entire repository, you can simply use "." (i.e. a single period character) as the module name.

Comment: Also, if ITitC is indeed the name of the module and not a branch, then you should lose the forward slash at the end.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in my first comment: I messed up the protocol in the example CVSROOT. Should of course be `:sserver:user@server:/CVSRepo`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right that the server string was broken in my obfuscation - it connects and starts pulling data when "ITitC" is replaced with ".". You're right in that ITitC is a module, not a branch - I will update the question.  I have removed the / from ITitC/ but that did not help - I am still receiving the error.  I cannot pull the entire repo (using ".") due to permissions which I have no control over.  Any other suggestions would be grealy appreciated.

Comment: Try: `C:\Program Files (x86)\CVS Suite\CVSNT\cvs.exe -d :sserver:user@server:/CVSRepo co ITitC`. Does that work?

Comment: @Sagar that worked perfectly from my command line. I don't know if I can force Hudson to use that simplified command, however. I shall investigate.

Comment: I do not think you can force Hudson to do so. You could use the "Windows Batch Command" to check out your module manually. However, Hudson will not be able to check for changes then. One other thing you can try (I do not know how much of a difference it makes), but try the non-gnu version of CVS. That is what we use, and I have had no problem with it (http://ftp.gnu.org/non-gnu/cvs/binary/stable/x86-woe/)

Comment: Great idea.  We're working with the Windows Batch Command now as a stop-gap measure and will continue to try to make the CVS plugin work for us after.

Answer (score 1):

We encountered same issue wit CVS 1.11.xx and were not able to solve it. In result we moved to CVS 1.12.xx and Hudson works fine. Seems this issue is specific to some CVS server builds and has not relation to CVS client.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue

```
[workspace] $ cvs.exe -Q -z3 -d :pserver:user@server01:/cvsrepo/projectrepo co -P -N -d . -D "Thursday, June 13, 2013 9:24:00 PM UTC" Module1 Module2
cvs.exe checkout: cannot open CVS/Entries for reading: No such file or directory
```

With only one module specified, the checkout works and the contents of the module are directly beneath the workspace folder created by Hudson. (there is no Module1 folder created)

For multiple modules, the checkout only works if a directory name is specified in the -d.  Using the default Hudson specified . is when the error occurs.

```
[workspace] $ cvs.exe -Q -z3 -d :pserver:user@server01:/cvsrepo/projectrepo co -P -N -d customDir -D "Thursday, June 13, 2013 9:53:46 PM UTC" Module1 Module2
$ computing changelog
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Specifying the customDir creates a customDir folder beneath workspace with Module1 and Module2 folders below it.

This behavior happens in the command line as well as inside Hudson so it must be a feature of CVS.